# How to test the order of an array in Karate

Tags: karate

I want to test that the array that I get back from an endpoint is in a particular order, based on a field in the object, using [Karate](https://github.com/intuit/karate). For example, I might have data that looks like this:

```
[
  { seconds: 20 },
  { seconds: 15 },
  { seconds: 12 }
]
```

My goal is to test that the objects are listed in descending order.

I have a successful implementation of this test, but I am looking for a better way of doing it, if possible. Here is what I did to test the order:

```
* def orderTest = function() { for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) { if(i !== 0 && response[i].seconds > response[i-1].seconds) return false; } return true; }
Then assert orderTest()
```

While this seems to work as expected, it is ***ugly***. Is there a better way to test the array's order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes ! It becomes simple if you extract the numbers alone into an array - which behind the scenes is just a Java `List` so you can apply the `Collections` methods on it:

```
* def Collections = Java.type('java.util.Collections')
* def response = 
"""
[
  { seconds: 20 },
  { seconds: 15 },
  { seconds: 12 }
]
"""
* def before = $response[*].seconds
* copy after = before
* Collections.sort(after, Collections.reverseOrder())
* match before == after
```

Comment: Hi @Peter Thomas how would this logic work for the array having floating values 

For example - 
[0.565345345, 0.3432432432, 1 , 0.8765465456, 0.565435433]

Comment: @vdrulerz should work. if it doesn't, follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue